# Javascript dynamic form submit

Tags: php, javascript, webforms

I am trying to write a script that will submit all the individual forms on a single page.
I start by counting the amount of forms, then using that count I iterate through each form and submit it.

On the PHP page each form is written like so:

```
<form name="order_driver_'.$j.'" class="order_container" id="save_'.$j.'"method="post" action="../scripts/order_driver_save.php">
```

I then use JavaScript to count each one and submit them:

```
    function count_form(){

    //Count the amount of outputs
    var count = $(".order_container").size();

    //Run loop for reults
    for(count=count;count>0;count--){

        //var save='order_driver_'+count;

        document.order_driver+count.submit();

    }
}
```

The issue I have is in the submit part:

```
document.order_driver_ + count.submit();
```

I can't concatenate the `var count` to the `.order_driver_`.

I am wondering how to do this so I can specify each form name to be submitted in the loop.

Comment: You could simplify that loop slightly with: `for(;count>0;count--) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to submit them via AJAX if you want them to all submit, because as soon as one is submitted, the browser will follow the request, and refresh the page.  So even if you got it to concatenate, it would only submit the first.

**UPDATE**

While I know i might get blasted by suggesting you use jquery, I think in this situation, it greatly simplifies what you need to do.

this code will accomplish your goal if you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
// #submit-click being whatever you want to initiate the mass form submit
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
    $('form').submit();
});

//form submit event handler
$('form').submit(function() {
    //get the form and serialize it's data
    var form = $(this);
    var data = form.serialize();

    //submit via AJAX
    $.post(form.attr('action'), data);

    //prevent the default action of submit
    return false;
});
```

notice that you will receive no confirmation that they have been submitted.

Comment: Cheers. I am confused. How is it looping to submit each form? should it be contained in the for statement?

Comment: sorry, yeah, part of this will be learning the way jQuery works, `$('form')` selects ALL form tags on the page, and so this code will attach the event to all form tags, and then on clicking of `$('#submit-button')` (anything with an id of `submit-button` ) it will submit all form elements.

Answer (score 1):

Note: you're going to have to make the calls separate from each other or the page will move to the target of the submit.  Either Ajax calls or make the target be in a new window.

Change it to get the element and submit that element:

```
function count_form(){

//Count the amount of outputs
var count = $(".order_container").size();

//Run loop for reults
for(count=count;count>0;count--){

    //var save='order_driver_'+count;

    document.getElementById("order_driver_" + count).submit();



}
}
```

Comment: +1: Answers his question, but unfortunately brings us to the crux of his real issue: submitting multiple forms at once.